# how to generate cosmos db CosmosDB Data Explorer URL

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there a Rest API to generate a URL for ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**No** there is NO API to generate this URL, you can refer the existing REST API methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/#cosmos-db-resources).